# Visual Studio Team Explorer and git in command line shows different status

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, team-explorer

I've very strange problem with Visual Studio 2013. Visual Studio Team Explorer shows some files in included changes list, but git from command line shows "nothing to commit, working directory clean". State of file in VS Team Explorer is "edit". Git version is 2.6, but in 1.9.5 the same problem occurs. Does anyone have similar problem?

EDIT: problem occurs when creating new file in solution from Visual Studio, new file is committed from command line (PowerShell).

Comment: Are you running VS 2013 Update 5?  If not, start there.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48129

Comment: @edward-thomson I have VS 2013 Update 5 already.

Comment: Which client is behaving the way you'd expect?  Do you expect them to show up in the changes list?  Or do you expect them to be ignored?  Do you have a `.gitignore` for these types of files?

Comment: @edward-thomson, Both clients behave as expected till committing. When I commit changes from PowerShell, git in PowerShell after 'git status' shows 'nothing to commit' but in Visual Studio Team Explorer committed file is still in Included changes list with status 'edit' on it.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio seems to be adding a file ms-persist.xml in the .git folder, that keeps track of file changes. Sometimes this file is out of sync. You can edit this file and remove the inconsistent files, or delete this file completely.

Comment: File @useless-hasid has mentioned is OK but the problem still occures.